# Determining class hierarchy of an object at runtime

Tags: php

`get_class()` will give me the eventual class of an object.

I want to know all the chain of parent classes. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could call [`get_parent_class`](http://php.net/get_parent_class) repeatedly until it returns *false*:

```
function getClassHierarchy($object) {
    if (!is_object($object)) return false;
    $hierarchy = array();
    $class = get_class($object);
    do {
        $hierarchy[] = $class;
    } while (($class = get_parent_class($class)) !== false);
    return $hierarchy;
}
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use

- [`class_parents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php) — Return all parent classes of the given class in an array

Example:

```
print_r(class_parents('RecursiveDirectoryIterator'));
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [FilesystemIterator] => FilesystemIterator
    [DirectoryIterator] => DirectoryIterator
    [SplFileInfo] => SplFileInfo
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for specific types, or build a function to create drilldown without using any of the other solutions, you could resort to 'instanceof' to determine if it's a specific type as well,  It will be true for checking if a class extends a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

The [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) class part of the [PHP Reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) has a [getParentClass()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) method.

Here's a small code sample using it:

```
<?php

class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }


$class = new ReflectionClass('C');
echo $class->getName()."\n";
while ($class = $class->getParentClass()) {
  echo $class->getName()."\n";
}
```

[Run the code](http://ideone.com/i6O8w)