# Get a PHP object's ancestors in the inheritance tree

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, parent, traversal

I have an object and want to list all parent classes up until stdClass or whatever.

I have added a polymorphic field to my database table (say categories) and want to automate my finder method so that super classes are also returned, this way i can jump into the inheritance tree at a point i know not necessarily the final subclass:

```
FoodCategory::find_by_id(10) === Category::find_by_id(10)

SELECT * FROM categories WHERE ..... AND type IN ('FoodCategory', 'Category');
```

Roughly i guess:

```
function get_class_lineage($object){
    $class = get_parent_class($object);
    $lineage = array();
    while($class != 'stdClass'){
        $dummy_object = new $class();
        $lineage[] = $class = get_parent_class($dummy_object);
    }

    return $lineage;
}
```

But this instantiates an object, does anyone know how to achieve this without?

Thanks for any input, i feel like i'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: determining class hierarchy of an object at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209201/php-determining-class-hierarchy-of-an-object-at-runtime)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After being pointed to the duplicate question i have gone for:

```
function get_class_lineage($object){
    $class_name = get_class($object);
    $parents = array_values(class_parents($class_name));
    return array_merge(array($class_name), $parents);
}
```

The class_parents function from the standard library was the obvious thing i was overlooking.

I thought Reflection was overkill for this simple task.

Answer (score 13):

**Using Reflection**

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($object);

$lineage = array();

while ($class = $class->getParentClass()) {
    $lineage[] = $class->getName();
}

echo "Lineage: " . implode(", ", $lineage);
```

[ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php) accepts either the name of the class or an object.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read at [manual](http://php.net/get-parent-class) you can also give a classname as a string to the function.

```
$class = get_class($this);
$lineage = array();
do {
  $lineage[] = $class;
  $class = get_parent_class($class);
} while ($class != 'stdClass');
```

Here index `0` is the classname of the object itself:

Comment: Not so hurting by now, I guess, but string classname requires PHP >= 5.1.0

Comment: Well, PHP 5.6 is not supported since 2018. So if one is using a version < 7.2 (current version, security fixes only), they have other problems, than string classnames. (For the curious ones: 5.0 had its EOL on 5 Sep 2005).