# Get list of parent classes

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [php: determining class hierarchy of an object at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209201/php-determining-class-hierarchy-of-an-object-at-runtime)

Is there a way to get a list of parent classes for a certain class?

For example:

```
class a{ 
    public function getParentsList(){...}
}

class b extends a{}

class c extends b{}

$c=new c;

var_dump($c->getParentsList());
```

should print array(a,b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the reflection classes http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

A working example seems to be this one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php#100978

Answer (score 1):

I've seen an answer to this before:

[Answered by michael at getsprink dot -- com on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php#90202)